# Событие click срабатывает два раза

Tags: javascript, click

После заполнения 3 полей ввода оставшиеся поля блокируются, и появляется кнопка "сбросить". При ее нажатии все поля открываются, и счетчик заполненных полей обновляется. При проверке значений счетчика в консоли увидел, что после нажатия кнопки сброса при вводе значения в одно поле счетчик увеличивается два раза, а не один. В чем моя ошибка?

https://spleekz.github.io/trinagle1/

(нужный фрагмент кода описан под комментарием 'блок инпутов').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
calcFields.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.target.classList.contains ('input')){
        event.target.addEventListener('change',function(){ // !!!
            if(event.target.value !==''){
                i++;
                ...
```

Не добавляйте обработчики событий внутри других обработчиков событий (кроме "DOMContentLoaded"). Они накапливаются и выстреливают все.

---

> Обработчиков на событие будет прикреплено столько, сколько раз
> вызывется `addEventListener`

Опа. Я был неправ.

```js
function clickEventHandler() {
  console.log("clickEventHandler");
}
var btn = document.getElementById("test");
function addEvent() {
  btn.addEventListener("click", clickEventHandler);
  console.log("addEvent");
}
function removeEvent() {
  btn.removeEventListener("click", clickEventHandler);
  console.log("removeEvent");
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
<button onclick="addEvent()">Add</button>
<button onclick="removeEvent()">Remove</button>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

> If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same
> EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are
> discarded.

Comment: А если, при добавлении обработчиков, использовать не анонимную функцию, то не должны накапливаться... так или нет?

Comment: @UModeL Нет, не так. Обработчиков на событие будет прикреплено столько, сколько раз вызывется `addEventListener` - конечно, если между ними не вызывается `removeEventListener`.

Comment: тогда получается, что `removeEventListener` удаляет разом все одноимённые обработчики?

Comment: @UModeL А это мы сейчас выясним.

Comment: @UModeL Я был неправ.

Comment: т.е. именованные функи заменяют друг друга и удаляются по имени, а анонимные прирастают, без возможности удаления, так?

Comment: @UModeL Их можно удалить все разом.

Comment: но, те, что без имени - их то не удалить? Во всяком случае выборочно. И есть подозрения, что цитата из спеки к ним не относится.

Comment: @UModeL Она к ним не относится, потому что анонимная функция, определенная "in-place", каждый раз новая.

Comment: это хорошая тема для вопроса с самоответом ;-) Если что - с меня ++

Comment: @UModeL Согласен. Чуть позже. Сейчас должен идти ремонтировать подвал :).